# Flask - Data from database not rendering correctly on HTML - Need spaces between paragraph

Tags: html, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

My Flask app is uses a PSQL database which has a column that contains a story/article per row. Naturally, it has line breaks for new paragraphs. The view function stores the data that comes from SQLAlchemy in a variable `data` which then returns the template html file along with the data variable. Finally HTML renders `{{ data.story }}` but in doing so, the HTML removes the line breaks for each paragraph (bunching it up into one big paragraph, which is not correct). I have tried serval approaches but none have worked. Here are the approaches I have tried:

1. asdfs `<br><br>` dsdf
2. asdfs `\n` dsdf
3. asdfs `\\\n` dsdf
4. asdfs `\r\n` dsdf
5. asdfs `\\r\\n` dsdf
6. asdfs `<br/>` dsdf
7. In CSS `.display-linebreak { white-space: pre-line;` }
   In HTML `<div className="display-linebreak">  </div>`

Here is the output I am getting (not correct):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor   
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud  
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <br><br>
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Here is what the desired output should be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor   
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud  
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.
```

How can I fix this issue, so that the paragraphs are shown correctly (i.e. not bunched up)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
asds<br/>dada
```

Comment: I just did. Unfortunately, it did not work. I am adding it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to my issue. First ensure the story/articles field in the database has `"<br>"` where the new paragraph would be.

Then in the view:

```
@app.route('/') 
def index():
    data = Tablename.query.filter_by(id=1).all()
    data = data[0].columnname
    obj = data.replace('<br>', '\n\n')
    return render_template('index.html', data=obj)
```

Finally in the HTML template change `{{data}}` to:

```
 <span style="white-space: pre-line">{{data}}</span>
```